# Windows System Color for Page Cotrol

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10

Is there any Windows function that knows which color is used for page control lines/tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetThemeColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-getthemecolor) with `TABP_TABITEM` for `iPartId`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is `TMT_EDGEFILLCOLOR` for iPropId

```
hTabTheme = OpenThemeData(0, VSCLASS_TAB = 'TAB');
GetThemeColor( hTabTheme,
               1 = TABP_TABITEM, 
               0 = All&Default or 1 = TIS_NORMAL, 
               3808 = TMT_EDGEFILLCOLOR,
               @myColor);
CloseThemeData(hTabTheme);
```

More info for [iPart and iState](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/windows/desktop/Controls/property-typedefs) and for [iPropId](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/windows/desktop/Controls/parts-and-states)